# Mapping form.io responses to a postgress DB

Tags: mongodb, formio

I am considering using Form.IO Open Source which would be installed on AWS as the front end of an existing app that has a postgress dB.

I am very new to this and I can not tell if you can use the [resquel](https://github.com/formio/resquel) library allows you to map the form responses directly to a SQL database or does it map the form response saved to its mongo database to a SQL database?

I really do not want to use the Mongo DB at all and am hoping that form responses can be mapped directly without saving to a Mongo DB

Any insight into this is greatly appreciated

thank you

Comment: What pricing tier are you on ?

Comment: Using the `open-source`, was thinking of ditching the mongo DB altogether and mapping the json directly